# Jquery multiselect deselect all options except the newly-selected one automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, jquery-ui-multiselect

I'm using jquery bootstrap multiselect using  [this documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/). My scripts looks like this:

```
  <script id="example">
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#demo').multiselect({
      enableClickableOptGroups: true,
      enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
     });
  });
  </script>
```

I had inserted  optgroups, in each one there is 4 option.

```
 <select id="demo" multiple="multiple" >
<optgroup label="Group 1">
  <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
  <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
  <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
  <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 111">
  <option value="1-1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2-1">Option 2</option>
  <option value="2-2">Option 3</option>
  <option value="2-3">Option 4</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 12">
  <option value="1-1">Option 5</option>
  <option value="2-1">Option 6</option>
  <option value="2-2">Option 7</option>
  <option value="2-3">Option 8</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Group 63">
  <option value="1-1">Option 63.4</option>
  <option value="2-1">Option 63.1</option>
  <option value="2-2">Option 63.2</option>
  <option value="2-3">Option 63.3</option>
</optgroup>
```

Here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/etzacv5k/2/

The problem is when i check "Group 1", it is checked, then, when i select "Group 111", the previous one is deselected, and the new one is selected, same for the last group, when i check the last one, all previous ones are deselected. I want it to persist selected when because its multiple choice.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Try with adding:

enableFiltering: true,

or can you create a fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/etzacv5k/2/ here is it i will update the question

Comment: it works in the fiddle. i don't see any problem

Comment: try to check group 1, after that, check group 12 , it will uncheck the group 1 
One other : try to check first 3 ones, and then uncheck the third one

Comment: looks like a bug. from: http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-enableCollapsibleOptGroups  Again, note, that the behavior of combining enableCollapsibleOptGroups, enableCollapsibleOptGroups, enableFiltering and includeSelectAllOption is not thoroughly tested. Experiment with the example below to get some intuition.

Comment: i didnt found any documentation about this bug

Comment: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/836

Comment: until now its not solved i guess !

Comment: Actually, i solved the issue by changing the bootstrap-multiselect.js version , i used the one from davidstutz.
http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i solved the issue by changing the bootstrap-multiselect.js version , i used the one from davidstutz.

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js